# Tkinter will not check checkbox using loaded value

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot load a checkbox value from a file and have it correctly check the checkbox when the value is 1.

With the code below you can check a box and save it to a file.  Clicking Load will load that value into a second variable, convert it to Int and create a checkbox linked to its value, but it will never generate already checked, even when the value of it's variable is 1 as shown by the print command.  What am I doing wrong?

```
Window = Tk()

var = IntVar()
LoadVarTemp = 0
LoadVar = IntVar()

def SaveIt():
    YesVar = var.get()
    with open("config.txt", "w") as configfile:
        configfile.write(str(YesVar))

def LoadIt():
    with open("config.txt") as file:
        content = file.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    LoadVarTemp = content[0]
    LoadVar = int(LoadVarTemp)
    print(LoadVar)
    Checkbutton(Window, text="Loaded", variable=LoadVar).grid(row=1)

YesCheck = Checkbutton(Window, text="Yes?", variable = var).grid(row=0)
SaveButton = Button(Window, text="Save", command=SaveIt).grid(row=2)
LoadButton = Button(Window, text="Load", command=LoadIt).grid(row=3)

Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `variable=` and similar options of Tkinter widgets requires one of the specific var types - `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc.  Your `LoadVar` was originally such an object, but when loading from the config file you overwrote it with a plain integer, which is not usable for this purpose.  You need to call `.set()` on the `IntVar` in order to change its value.

Comment: Thank you so much, change LoadVar = int(LoadVarTemp) to LoadVar.set(int(LoadVarTemp)) fixed it right up.  This has been driving me nuts for a week now!